# Output Nancy/Swagger metadata using CamelCase

Tags: json.net, autofac, swagger, nancy, swagger-ui

Using Nancy, Autofac and Swagger-UI, I am having a problem with the output provided by the Nancy Metadata modules.

When looking through the model description that is automatically generated, all the properties are named with the first letter as an uppercase letter - PascalCase.

In the attached picture, there are two properties "Area" and "Values as described in Swagger.

[image: Model description with PascalCase]

In the actual output generated, I get the output as requested, with CamelCase:

```
[
   {
     "area" : "my area",
     "values" : [
       // stuff
     ]
   }
]
```

How can I force the metadata generated by Nancy and Swagger to render the model description using PascalCasing with first letter as lower letter?

Have had a look at the model binding defined by Nancy and the JsonSerializerSettings but without success.

Can it be that I am using the AutofacNancyBootstrapper, and that it messes the things up?